# Deadlock while using ORMLite

Tags: java, postgresql, ormlite

I have a multithreaded server Java application which receives requests and does queries/updates to a Postgres DB through OrmLite. Under load, several requests come in which are interested in the same DB row. `Thread1` might `select`, change values and then `update`. At the same time `Thread2` tries something similar. This is currently not synchronized and not done inside a transaction. Without surprise, the update of `Thread1`, might not be seen by `Thread2`. That's OK (`Thread2` can overwrite results from `Thread1`) and is not my problem.

However, when running this application for some time, I get to a deadlock situation, which results in all available DB connections being used up (and then crash). It seems it is not a standard deadlock (with a circular lock dependency), instead most threads are waiting on a lock, and the thread holding this lock seems to be waiting for a socket read (which probably does not happen, see below).

Using

- OrmLite 5.1,
- JVM is Java 1.8.0_251 Hotspot Client VM,
- Postgres JDBC 42.2.9

**How should I go forward to fix this?**

Below are relevant parts of the thread dump (analyzed by https://spotify.github.io/threaddump-analyzer )

The thread holding the main lock (`0x00000000c0179e18`), seems to be waiting on a socket:

```
"RaspService-2089": running, holding [0x00000000c0179e18, 0x00000000c2c1f6c0]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:335)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:505)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.makeConnection(JdbcConnectionSource.java:266)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java:140)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.update(BaseDaoImpl.java:408)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.update(OrmLite.java:361)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.CachedDao.update(CachedDao.java:287)
    at vgs.vigi.ble.RaspClient.run(RaspClient.java:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

26 threads waiting to free connections wait on that lock with stacks like:

```
"pool-4-thread-96": waiting to acquire [0x00000000c0179e18], holding [0x00000000c0b250a8]
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource.releaseConnection(JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java:168)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:331)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.create(OrmLite.java:181)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.CachedDao.create(CachedDao.java:126)
    at vgs.vigi.logic.Notification.sendNotification(Notification.java:491)
    at vgs.vigi.logic.Notification$1.run(Notification.java:640)
    at vgs.lib.MyTimer$2.run(MyTimer.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

More threads waiting to release connections

```
"RaspService-828": waiting to acquire [0x00000000c0179e18], holding [0x00000000c1187f88]
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource.releaseConnection(JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java:168)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.update(BaseDaoImpl.java:412)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.update(OrmLite.java:361)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.CachedDao.update(CachedDao.java:287)
    at vgs.vigi.ble.CmdRaspExcutor$8.exec(CmdRaspExcutor.java:318)
    at vgs.vigi.ble.RaspClient.run(RaspClient.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

While many also try to acquire connections:

```
"RaspService-991": waiting to acquire [0x00000000c0179e18], holding [0x00000000c1624058]
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java:125)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.update(BaseDaoImpl.java:408)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.update(OrmLite.java:361)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.CachedDao.update(CachedDao.java:287)
    at vgs.vigi.ble.RaspClient.run(RaspClient.java:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Some GC is happening (`inconsistent` means Thread is "BLOCKED (on object monitor)" without waiting for anything)

```
"qtp1719311117-931": inconsistent?, holding [0x00000000eabfc510]
    at java.lang.Runtime.gc(Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.gc(System.java:993)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.clearCache(OrmLite.java:33)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.dao(OrmLite.java:215)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.getAll(OrmLite.java:300)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.CachedDao.getAll(CachedDao.java:227)
    at vgs.lib.Ajax.sGetAll(Ajax.java:101)
    ...
```

And also GC in another thread (which is explicitely coded in our code - not sure why though)

```
"RaspService-1882": running, holding [0x00000000c05c84c8, 0x00000000c2bed7b0]
    at java.lang.Runtime.gc(Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.gc(System.java:993)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.clearCache(OrmLite.java:33)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.dao(OrmLite.java:215)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.update(OrmLite.java:360)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.CachedDao.update(CachedDao.java:285)
    at vgs.vigi.ble.RaspClient.run(RaspClient.java:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can I expect OrmLite to be safe with a multithreaded approach as described?

Are there best practices to avoid this issue (while still keeping the multithreaded nature of the server)?

---

### Update

I have a thread dump of a second run, which looks a bit different.

Here the thread holding the lock that everyone is waiting for is inconsistent

```
"RaspService-1405": inconsistent?, holding [0x00000000c01da9b8, 0x00000000c1cfed28]
```

With a raw stack of:

```
"RaspService-1405" #1469 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021579800 nid=0xa2f4 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002b36e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java:125)
    - locked <0x00000000c01da9b8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.update(BaseDaoImpl.java:408)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.update(OrmLite.java:361)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.CachedDao.update(CachedDao.java:287)
    at vgs.vigi.ble.RaspClient.run(RaspClient.java:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000c1cfed28> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

There is also a RUNNING thread which reads from a connection. Not sure whether that is blocked:

```
"RaspService-1410": running, holding [0x00000000ed1877c8, 0x00000000c1cfe208]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:335)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2008)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:158)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.update(JdbcDatabaseConnection.java:294)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.update(JdbcDatabaseConnection.java:217)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedUpdate.update(MappedUpdate.java:101)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.update(StatementExecutor.java:472)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.update(BaseDaoImpl.java:410)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.OrmLite.update(OrmLite.java:361)
    at vgs.vigi.servlet.CachedDao.update(CachedDao.java:287)
    at vgs.vigi.ble.RaspClient.run(RaspClient.java:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Update 2:

Here's a graph of sessions as seen from pgAdmin
[image]

Comment: What sort of connection settings are there on the PG connections?  Is there some sort of IO or connection timeout that should be set?

Comment: I assume that the connection waiting on read stays that way for a while?

Comment: @Gray I have updated with a dump from a second run. I have only 1 dump per run, so cannot judge if the stacks evolve, but given that many threads are waiting on it, I assume it is not releasing the lock for a long time. I am currently running the server in a single thread version which does not block and still handles the load (so it's certainly not a pure performance issues). Will get back to you on connection details.

Comment: @Gray regarding connection, PG offers a timeout to close idle connections, but we are not currently using this and I think it should not be necessary. If connections are returned to the pool normally, only a few connections should necessary.

Comment: There's not much ORMLite can do if the read never returns.  I could look into not locking around the create-connection but I'm not sure if that makes sense.  I was hoping that there was some sort of I/O timeout so that if the client didn't get a response from the server in a certain number of millis, it would timeout and the create connection would then fail.  This sounds to me like a postgres question rather than an ORMLite one.

Comment: Following the suggestion of @Alexander Pavlov, I'm investigating connection leakage. We are using a single `JdbcPooledConnectionSource` for the whole application. Can there be connection leakage with it? E.g. if DAOs are not GCed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> seems to be waiting on a socket:

It waits until new connection is created, also holding `lock` inside pool.

Do you have session limit in Postgres? If you do I suggest you set it slightly bigger than pool size in Java.

Otherwise, it is easy to have deadlock if pool size is equal to sessions limit size

1. All connections are taken (Java pool limit is reached, session count limit is reached)
2. Application tries to get new connection, takes pool lock and blocked by PG
3. Application tries to release connection, it cannot take pool lock so cannot release connection to PG, so session limit is still reached

Comment: We have increased the session limit to 500. When the deadlcok happens, we see the number of session go up until the crash. It takes about a minute with our traffic. The ThreadPool which handles incoming connections is not limited in size.

When running the server single threaded (all connection are handled by one single thread), there is no crash and the load can still be handled.

Comment: what is connection pool size?

Comment: hm, as per https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/jdbc/JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java they do not have JDBC connection pool limit. If you have more than 500 simultaneous connections or if you leak connections then you can exhaust 500 session limit in PG and get into deadlock

Comment: In normal operation, it does not leak connection, so I doubt this is it. It seems to be specifically linked with several threads accessing the DB (or a specific table) at the same time. As the socket read is waiting on input, this means that the TCP connection is still open. Why is there no answer from the DB on that connection?

Comment: Look at stack trace - there are `makeConnection/openConnection`

Comment: They have `getOpenCount() / getMaxConnectionsEverUsed()` - is it logged anywhere? If it is not can you add some timer to log it every minute to see values before and after deadlock. Trend also may give you some clues about what's happening.

Comment: Please see my update in the main question with a graph from pgAdmin. This is what I have available now.

Comment: So sessions (==connections) are leaking. You have ~500 idle connections

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate this. In the graph you see that the number of connections is very low during normal operation and then suddenly increases. Shouldn't connection leaking be showing continuously?